# how can i find (something) and replace after every one (something) using notepad++ and regular expression

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I have a huge xml file,
and there are so much tables I want to design after every 1 row background ( I can do it using nth-child(odd) css but I have limitation for using inline css.)
this is sample table

```
    <tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">প্রাণীবিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">১০০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">উদ্ভিদ বিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">১০০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মনোবিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৫০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">ক্রপ সায়েন্স এন্ড টেকনোলজী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মানবিক ১৬ , বিজ্ঞান ২০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">ফার্মেসী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">২৫</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">জেনেটিক ইঞ্জিনিয়ারিং এন্ড বায়োটেকনোলজী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৩০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মাইক্রোবায়োলজি</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৩৫</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">ভূগোল ও পরিবেশ বিদ্যা</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">বিজ্ঞান ৩০, মানবিক ২০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">প্রাণরসায়ন ও অনুপ্রাণ বিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৩৫</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মৃত্তিকা বিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৫০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s"></td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">সর্বমোট আসন সংখ্যা</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৪৬১</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s"></td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to find `<tr>` and replace after every one `<tr>` with `<tr style="background:#ddd">`.

I want this

```
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">প্রাণীবিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">১০০</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background:#ddd">
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">উদ্ভিদ বিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">১০০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মনোবিজ্ঞান</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৫০</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background:#ddd">
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">ক্রপ সায়েন্স এন্ড টেকনোলজী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মানবিক ১৬ , বিজ্ঞান ২০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">ফার্মেসী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">২৫</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background:#ddd">
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">জেনেটিক ইঞ্জিনিয়ারিং এন্ড বায়োটেকনোলজী</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৩০</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-center wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">মাইক্রোবায়োলজি</td>
<td class="text-center wow slideInRight" data-wow-duration="1.5s">৩৫</td>
</tr>
```

ভূগোল ও পরিবেশ বিদ্যা
    বিজ্ঞান ৩০, মানবিক ২০
    
    
    প্রাণরসায়ন ও অনুপ্রাণ বিজ্ঞান
    ৩৫
    
    
    মৃত্তিকা বিজ্ঞান
    ৫০
    
    
    
    
    
    
    সর্বমোট আসন সংখ্যা
    ৪৬১

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrated here: http://regexr.com/3dnq1

Every third 'abc' will be replaced with 'defg'

```
/((?:abc[^abc]+){2})abc /g
```

This would turn

```
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

into

```
abc abc defg abc abc defg abc abc defg abc abc defg abc
```

just remember to put *defg* in the replace box

and change the {2} to {3} etc to match how many matches you want in between each replace

**EDIT TO FIT OP's EDIT:**

Demonstrated here: https://regex101.com/r/zD3cP9/1

Use:

```
((?:<tr.*?){2})>
```

and 'replace all' with

```
\1 style="background:#ddd">
```

Comment: it's working for abc with white space but not for this :(

Comment: @IbrahimAkbar I modified my answer to fit your criteria.

Comment: yes, it's works! thanks :)

Comment: @IbrahimAkbar Glad to see it works! Could you then put my answer as accepted?

Comment: Yes, I checked it as accepted, thanks sir.. :)